# How to make an inventory program execute

Tags: python

I'm still learning python. I am trying to write a program that develops a car inventory. I am creating an `automobile` class that will be used by a dealership as a vehicle inventory program. The following attributes should be present in your automobile class:

```
private string make
private string model
private string color
private int year
private int mileage
```

How can I make this execute and give prompts for input. It's not doing it.

```
class Automobile():
    __make = ""
    __model = ""
    __color = ""
    __year = 0
    __mileage = 0


    def __init__(self, make = None, model = None, color = None, year = None, mileage = None):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.mileage = mileage

    def add_vehicle(self):
        auto = Automobile()
        vehicle_file = open('vehicle.txt', 'a')
        make = input("Enter make: ")
        model = input("Enter model: ")
        color = input("Enter color: ")
        year = input("Enter year: ")
        mileage = input("Enter mileage: ")

        vehicles = Automobile(make, model, color, year, mileage)
        vehicle_list = [vehicles.make, vehicles.model, vehicles.color, vehicles.year, vehicles.mileage]

        for item in vehicle_list:
            vehicle_file.write("%s\t" % item)
        vehicle_file.write("\n")
        vehicle_file.close()
        print("Your record has been succesfully added to the inventory")

    def delete_vehicle(self):
        del_rec = input("Enter record to delete: ")

        with open("vehicle.txt","r+") as f:
            new_f = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            for line in new_f:
                if del_rec not in line:
                    f.write(line)
            f.truncate()
        print("Succesfully deleted record from inventory")

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.make = make

    def get_make(self):
        return self.make

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def get_model(self):
        return self.model

    def set_color(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def get_color(self):
        return self.color

    def set_year(self, year):
        self.year = year

    def get_year(self):
        return self.year

    def set_mileage(self, mileage):
        self.mileage = mileage

    def get_mileage(self):
        return self.mileage
```

Comment: Make a basic python tutorial first. You can not just copy code from `java` or `c++` of whatever you learned first and try to make it look like `python`. There is so much wrong with this code.

Comment: 1. Never use `getter` and `setter` functions. 2. Never use double underscore name. Use properties instead if 1 and 2. 3. You need global code that gets executed.